# macOS Kauth API lack vnode rename prevention

Tags: macos, kernel, authorization, kernel-extension, xnu

In order to protect my project file from being deleted by unauthorized entities, I used `kauth_listen_scope` with `KAUTH_SCOPE_VNODE` option to add new callback function that prevent other from deleting those files.

However, it appears that it's possible to move those files to trash from `Finder` since it uses the `rename` system call. this command doesn't trigger vnode authorization event that can be prevented, only fileop event (but these are for detection only).

Perhaps anyone have an alternative about what can be done in order to prevent this action ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

So it appears that `rename` sys call also goes through vnode authorization.

However, it does not request authorization on the file itself, but on its container (parent directory).